# Bootstrap: fix top bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

> Is possible to fix that bar so is always visible during the scroll?

I need to fix the navigation and the first top bar (the one with the logo) during the scroll.

HTML code:

```
<!--*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*- Start Logo Bar *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-->

<div class="container-fluid logo-bar">      
        <div class="container">         
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-9">

                    <div class="row">

                        <!--======= Text =========-->
                        <div class="col-md-4 logo_bar_icons">

                            <h2 class="first-text"><b>Wohnen</b>,<br>wie es <b>gefällt.</b></h2>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <!--======= Logo =========-->
                <div class="col-md-3">

                    <a href="index.html">
                        <img src="img/logo_2.png" class="img-responsive"  alt="Logo" id="" />
                    </a>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div> 

<!--*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*- End Logo Bar *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-->
```

Comment: use two section in nav

Comment: add the property position:fixed on your top bar. See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be very easy to get a fixed toolbar.

Here's an example from the bootstrap site [navbar-fixed-top](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/)

You could try wrapping everything with

```
.navbar-fixed-top
```

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap it is very easy. All you need to do is to add a class .navbar-fixed-top to the first nav element. The class is predefined in bootstrap css and it add sometling like this:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1030;      
}
```

So you see, that it is allways on top ob the document (top: 0;) and is fixed on that position (position: fixed;).

Comment: yeah, the navigation now is fixed, but how to fix also the first top bar during scroll? The one with the logo...

Answer (score 0):

This is directly from getbootstrap.com and is what you're looking for.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="../../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
      </div>

    </div><!-- /.container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yeah, the navigation now is fixed, but how to fix also the first top bar during scroll? The one with the logo...

Answer (score 0):

yes,it Is possible using **navbar-fixed-top** .

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a></div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
   
    
    
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a></div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yeah, the navigation now is fixed, but how to fix also the first top bar during scroll? The one with the logo...

Comment: sorry , i can't understand !